# Why am I getting a MessageRejected error?

Tags: amazon-ses, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a lambda to send emails using the aws sdkv3 for javascript.  I am sending to verified email address.  The exception returned does not tell me what the root causes might be as it is not one of their common errors.

Please look at my code and tell me if anyone sees and error in them template or the code.

```
exports.sendTestEmail = async (address, task_id) => {
  console.log(`send email to ${address}`);
  const tmpltChngParams = {
    Destination: { /* required */
      CcAddresses: [],
      ToAddresses: [address]
    },
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Html: {
          Data: '<p> There was a change made  that has impacted Requirements Submission.'
                        + 'A task has been created to track this process.</p>',
          Charset: 'utf-8'
        },
        Text: {
          Data: 'There was a change made that has impacted Requirements Submission. '
                        + 'A task has been created to track this process.',
          Charset: 'utf-8'
        }
      },
      Subject: {
        Data: ` System Notification: Task ${task_id}, `,
        Charset: 'utf-8'
      }
    },
    Source: 'aws-notifications-acct_num@someplace.com', /* required */
    ReplyToAddresses: [],
  };
  const sesclient = new SES({ region: 'us-east-1' });
  const command = new SendEmailCommand(tmpltChngParams);
  try {
    const sendPromise = await sesclient.send(command);

    console.log(`Message ID = ${sendPromise.MessageId}`);
    return sendPromise;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err, err.stack);
    return err;
  }
};
```

When trying to send I get the following exception in the logs:

```
2021-08-11T13:26:18.210Z    e40afcd0-99f1-47ad-90bc-1c7d95f82699    ERROR   MessageRejected: MessageRejected
    at deserializeAws_querySendEmailCommandError (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-ses/dist/cjs/protocols/Aws_query.js:3368:41)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-serde/dist/cjs/deserializerMiddleware.js:6:20
    at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist/cjs/middleware.js:12:24
    at async StandardRetryStrategy.retry (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist/cjs/defaultStrategy.js:56:46)
    at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist/cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:6:22
    at async Object.exports.sendTestEmail (/var/task/emailTest.js:34:25)
    at async /var/task/routes/countryOwnersRoutes.js:77:16
    at async /var/task/node_modules/lambda-api/index.js:231:23 {
  '$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 400,
    requestId: '3f5f10fe-2c95-43e1-a720-a859bd7abc84',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  }
} MessageRejected: MessageRejected
    at deserializeAws_querySendEmailCommandError (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-ses/dist/cjs/protocols/Aws_query.js:3368:41)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-serde/dist/cjs/deserializerMiddleware.js:6:20
    at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-signing/dist/cjs/middleware.js:12:24
    at async StandardRetryStrategy.retry (/var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-retry/dist/cjs/defaultStrategy.js:56:46)
    at async /var/task/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist/cjs/loggerMiddleware.js:6:22
    at async Object.exports.sendTestEmail (/var/task/emailTest.js:34:25)
    at async /var/task/routes/countryOwnersRoutes.js:77:16
    at async /var/task/node_modules/lambda-api/index.js:231:23
```

Comment: Did you find out the cause of the error?

Comment: @tteguayco - I had to switch back to sdkv2 to get this to work.  I think AWS made sdkv3 unnecessarily complex and over engineered.